# Insert SQL request in Power BI

Tags: sql, database, powerbi, request

Who can help me with inserting a SQL request in Power BI?

I want to insert a SQL request in Power BI. I have a project in Power BI where I need to use Excel files, but I'm unsure about how to insert a SQL request in Power BI to execute it.

"a SQL request": Refers to a query written in the Structured Query Language (SQL), which is used to retrieve data from a database.

"in Power BI": Refers to the software tool called Power BI, which is used for data analysis and visualization. The person is specifically looking to understand how to add an SQL query within the Power BI environment.

Comment: Maybe https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/databases/sql-server/bi-sql-server/power-bi-introduction-working-with-sql-server-data-in-power-bi-desktop-part-5/   or https://sqlspreads.com/blog/creating-reports-with-power-bi-sql-and-excel/

Answer (score 0):

1. Open Power BI
2. Go to "Home" (in spanish is "Inicio").
   [image]
3. Select "SQL Server". Your credentials will be required.
4. Select "Advanced options"

[image]

5. In the "SQL statement" box is where you can write your SQL query.